# Twinkling and shining like a star in the sky, laughing and crying - but who am I?

Tags: riddle

> The words on the page
> Arranged in neat lines
> Like a play on a stage
> When done well - there I shine.
>
> On joyful, bright days
> And downcast, sad ones too
> When you meet someone's gaze
> I'll be there, clear and true.
>
> Anger burns and flares out
> And I'm there in the hurt
> If you yell, scream, and shout
> I wipe away dust and dirt.
>
> Like the slow patter of rain
> Or ebbing waves like the sea
> Coming fast like a train
> Or quietly sitting, like a nice cup of tea.
>
> There are some who misuse me
> Teeth as sharp as a knife.
> But you do really need me
> I'm the salt (not the spice) in your salad of life.
>
> When you've lost something dear
> I'm there like a friend
> You have nothing to fear
> After all, I might be a good thing, in the end.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be

> a tear (- and a nice poem aswell).

When done well - there I shine.

> A good book or play can create emotions and so tears (joyful or painful).

I wipe away dust and dirt.

> Tears kind of wash your face.

Coming fast like a train
or quietly sitting, like a nice cup of tea.

> Crying out loud or just let a single teardrop appear in your eye.

I'm the salt (not the spice) in your salad of life.

> you are indeed salty.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> your eyes?

Explanation:

> Your eyes shine whenever you do something well.
>
>  Your eyes  meet another's gaze.
>
>  Your eyelashes keep out dirt and dust.

Comment: I've put spoiler blocks to hide your answer. In general, on this site, answers to riddles should have the important bits in spoilers to allow others to solve it by themselves.

Comment: Thank you bobble. I am a new person on here so you helping me out is really appreciated.